# Is there a simple way to sort by numbers then by letters of amino acid in python

Tags: python, sorting, alphanumeric

Is there a simple way to sort alphanumerically but in numerical increments then starting the letters again at next numeral 
yes a capitol letter followed w/ no spaces up to a 5 digit number
python, amino acid sequence numbers?

In Python I've tried:

```
from natsort import natsort_keygen, ns
l1 = ['D1', 'E1', 'S1', 'S4', 'S6', 'C1', 'S2', 'D2', 'C2', 'E2', 'W373']
natsort_key1 = natsort_keygen(key=lambda y: y.lower())
l1.sort(key=natsort_key1)
l1

# Gives: 
['C1', 'C2', 'D1', 'D2', 'E1', 'E2', 'S1', 'S2', 'S4', 'S6', 'W373']
```

BUT id like it as:

```
['C1', 'D1', 'E1', 'S1', 'C2','D2', 'E2', 'S2', 'S4', 'S6', 'W373']
```

Comment: Can Amino Acids have two letters?

Comment: @GiantsLoveDeathMetal Please refrain from sarcasm and setting yourself up to answer your own questions.

Comment: @8protons It is legitimate to not delete his comment and answer it himself in this case imho. I didn't know there was only one letter, the information was missing in the original question, others might not know it either, and it is kinda crucial for the problem.

Comment: @bgse Good point, maybe I inferred his two comments wrong and given that there is a 7 minute space between the two, I think you're right. My apologies to GiantsLoveDeathMetal for a possible incorrect assumption. BUT- I'd still argue that the first comment is unnecessary and that simply saying, "Amino acids cannot have two letters" would suffice. Regardless, the comment is irrelevant. C1, C2, E1, E2, etc are legitimate names regarding amino acid protein binding regions, terminals, and more.

Comment: I agree with both of you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this sort:

```
amino_acids = ['D1', 'E1', 'S1', 'S4', 'S6', 'C1', 'S2', 'D2', 'C2', 'E2', 'W373']

sorted_acids = sorted(
    amino_acids,
    key=lambda acid: (int(acid[1:]), acid[0])
)
```

Should be fine cause [Amino Acids](http://www.fao.org/docrep/004/Y2775E/y2775e0e.htm) only have one letter.

Comment: There is a typo in variable name on 4th line, it should be `amino_acid`

Answer (score 1):

You can use python's [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) function

`sorted(sorted(l1), key = lambda value:value[:1], value[0])`

output:
`['C1', 'D1', 'E1', 'S1', 'C2', 'D2', 'E2', 'S2', 'S4', 'S6', 'W373']`

Comment: @GiantsLoveDeathMetal Yeah, made the correction, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct that amino acids are represented by a single alphabet followed by a number then the following should do the trick.

```
from natsort import natsort_keygen, ns
l1 = ['D1', 'E1', 'S1', 'S4', 'S6', 'C1', 'S2', 'D2', 'C2', 'E2', 'W373']
for k, v in enumerate(l1):
    l1[k] = v[1:] + v[0]
natsort_key1 = natsort_keygen(key=lambda y: y.lower())
l1.sort(key=natsort_key1)
for k, v in enumerate(l1):
    l1[k] = v[-1] + v[:-1]
l1
```

This would sort take the first char to the end of the string, sort it and then bring it back and should do the trick.

Again, I don't know much about amino acids and the first google search result suggested that there's only one char followed by numbers. And my answer is based on that assumption

Comment: yes they(amino acids) are each 1 letter followed by as much as 5 digits, no spaces. these answers are excellent seem to work great.  thank you all.